# Mock: What Is the right way to mock sqlalchemy database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

This is what I've done for testing database

```
 @patch.object(query_functions, 'connection')   
    def test_service_reg_return_correct_data(self, mock_sqlalchmey):
        data = {                                                              
            "user_name": "testuser53",
            "password": "123456",
            "email_address": "testuser53@example.com",
            "dob": "2022-06-07 00:00:00",
            "address": "Ahmedabad",
            
        }
        
        # json_data = json.dumps(data)
        # print("jsob", json_data)
        m1 = mock.MagicMock()
        m1.get_json.return_value = data

       
        
        print("m", m1)
        with mock.patch("backened.routes.register.request", m1):
            
            response =user_register()
            self.assertTrue(mock_sqlalchmey.called)
            self.assertEqual(response.json, {'Message': 'New user Created'},201)
```

I've tested this function

```
def user_register():
    
    request_data = request.get_json()
    insert = service_register(request_data)
    print(type(insert))
    return insert
```

inside service_register(), I've run_insert() for execution of queries i.e query_functions.py file.

query_functions.py

```
def connection():

    engine = create_engine('mysql://root:admin@172.17.0.2:3306/flask', poolclass = NullPool)
    conn = engine.connect()
    return conn

def run_insert(data):
    conn = connection()
    sql = text(CONST_INSERT)
    
    print(sql)
    conn.execute(sql, data)
    conn.close()
    return ("executed")
```

I want to know whether it is right or wrong as I was trying to mock my database and don't want to insert data into DB. I'm not sure how database mock happened in this.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74771974/python-mock-how-to-mock-a-method-inside-a-fucntion) helps you?