# Python Mock: How to mock a method inside a fucntion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function in which I want to mock a method run_insert()

Structure:

```
"backened/routes/register.py"

def user_regsiter():
         service_register(request_data)


"backened/services/service_register.py"

def service_register(request_data):
         #some code
         validate()

         #some code
         run_insert(data)
```

in this user_register() will call service_register() and in that service_register()-> validate() and run_insert(data)

So , I want to mock run_register(data) in test function

```
"backened/sql/query_functions.py"

def run_insert(data):
    conn = connection()
    sql = text(CONST_INSERT) 
    print(sql)
    conn.execute(sql, data)
    conn.close()
    return ("executed")
```

this is what I've tried but getting **AssertionError: Expected 'run_insert' to have been called once. Called 0 times**

```
"backened/tests/test_users.py"

    @patch('backened.sql.query_functions.connection') 
    @patch('backened.sqlquery_functions.run_insert', return_value = "executed")
    def test_service_reg_return_correct_data(self, mock_sqlalchemy, mock_insert):
        
        data = {                                                              
            "user_name": "testuser57",
            "password": "123456",
            "email_address": "testuser57@example.com",
            "dob": "2022-06-07 00:00:00",
            "address": "Ahmedabad",
            
        }
        
        # json_data = json.dumps(data)
        # print("jsob", json_data)

        

        m1 = mock.MagicMock()
        m1.get_json.return_value = data
       

        print("m", m1)
        with mock.patch("backened.routes.register.request", m1):
            
            response =user_register()
            mock_sqlalchemy.assert_called_once()
            mock_insert.assert_called_once() 
            self.assertEqual(response.json, {'Message': 'New user Created'},201)
```

How to mock run_insert(data)?

Comment: What module is the `user_register` function defined in?

Comment: @mgilson I've made the changes added module path.

Comment: In that case, you probably want `@patch('backend.routes.register.run_insert', return_value='executed')` -- see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Comment: @mgilson in user_register() I'm calling service_register() and in that validate and run_insert() is present. I've updated the structure

Comment: In that case, you probably want `@patch('backend.services.service_register.run_insert', return_value='executed')` -- basically you just want to grab a reference to the function in the namespace where it is being used.

Comment: @mgilson now I'm getting AssertionError: Expected 'connection' to have been called once. Called 0 times.

Comment: Previously, `connection` was called inside the `run_insert` function but you have now replaced `run_insert` with a `Mock` so `connection` isn't getting called anymore.

Comment: @mgilson I suppose now there is no need to mock connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a functional and conceptual example inspired in your problem. You will need to adapt it to your need indeed.

What are the main points here.

- `sql_insert_data` is a method that returns an dict
- `service_register` is a method to execute a business logic with previous method as auxiliary
- `patch` method must have the path of object + method you want to mock

```
from sqlite3 import connect
from unittest import main, TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch


def sql_insert_data(data):
    conn = connect(":memory:")
    strSQL = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO table (field_1, field_2) VALUES (?, ?)"
    print(strSQL)
    conn.execute(strSQL, data)
    conn.close()
    return {'status': 'success'}

def service_register(row_data):
    sql_insert_data(row_data)
    return True


class TestMainService(TestCase):

    def test_service_register(self):
        with patch('__main__.sql_insert_data', return_value={'status': 'success'}) as mock_sql:
            service_register([123, 456])
            mock_sql.assert_called_once()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```